# Stay at Frankfurt/Main airport

Tags: germany, frankfurt

I will be arriving in Frankfurt one day before my flight via train. Is there any way to stay at the airport one night? And one more question: Is there any Internet cafe for taking documents print out. Please remember that the day I am travelling is on Sunday so is there any Internet cafe which opens on Sunday also?

Comment: Have you tried searching https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/services/hotels.html

Comment: If the flight is not early in the morning, staying in the city center next to the train station might be an interesting option. Airport hotels start at 100€/night while you can find a hotel room for less than 50€/night in the city. It's a 12 minute ride by S-Bahn to the airport, the price is 5€ for a one-way ride.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three hotels, probably more, within the Frankfurt Airport Complex. About an internet cafe inside the airport I am not sure. However, if you choose to stay at an hotel, then doing print-outs should not be a problem.